# Paint crack between wall and ceiling

Tags: paint, crack

We moved into this house 6 months ago, it was built in 2020, so practically new. Recently area experienced cold temperatures (down to -10s F). We were out during this time, but the thermostat was set to 60F all the time. Now it’s back to 40s, which is normal for winters here.

Once back, I noticed this kind of crack in two places, but they look exactly the same. The area is dry to touch.

Is this just a bad touch up job previous owner did before selling the house or is it something more serious? Would it be reasonable to fix it right away (then how?) or wait to make sure it's not growing / growing and then fix?

Thank you!

[image: crack]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's where a piece of bullnose (probably vinyl) runs into the ceiling. Taping the ceiling joint there is tricky. A stretchy, paintable caulk will hopefully fix it forever. Apply the caulk, push it into the joint and smooth it with your finger, wait, and paint.

I've seen that DAP has a paintable caulk for stuff like this called Stretch, but I have no idea if it's any good.